# ffmpeg error: Data doesn't look like RTP packets, make sure the RTP muxer is used

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, ffserver, muxer

I am trying to stream both video&audio from usbcam&mic throw ffmpeg over ffserver
I got 2 errors:
   - ffmpeg seems functionning but showing "Data doesn't look like RTP packets, make sure the RTP muxer is used"
   - i can connect to ffserver only for static files

here is server.conf file:

```
HTTPPort 1235
RTSPPort 1234
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 100000
#CustomLog –

########################################
##  static file for testing
########################################
#HTTP requests
<Stream media.flv>
File "/home/username/media.flv"
Format flv
</Stream>

#RTSP requests
<Stream media.mpg>
#preconverted file:
File "/home/username/media.mpg"
Format rtp
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoCodec libx264
VideoSize 720x720
StartSendOnKey
Preroll 0
</Stream>

##################################################
## usb cam
###################################################
<Feed test.ffm>
File /tmp/test.ffm
FileMaxSize 20K
ACL allow 192.168.1.149
</Feed>

<Stream usbcam.mpg>
Feed test.ffm
Format rtp
VideoFrameRate 25
VideoCodec libx264
VideoSize 720x720
PreRoll 0
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

my ffmpeg cmd is

```
ffmpeg -s 720x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 25 -f alsa -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 rtp://192.168.1.149:1234/test.ffm
```

it seems working but showing this error:

"Data doesn't look like RTP packets, make sure the RTP muxer is used"

when i stream the static files it works
but when i try to play usbcam stream throw ffplay and vlc nothing works

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

you can try tell to ffmpeg what is your output muxer format. (-f rtp)

```
ffmpeg -s 720x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 25 -f alsa -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.149:1234/test.ffm
```

Comment: I've already tried that but I got:   "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument"
Thanks for helping

Comment: I think that you need use one port per stream like:  `ffmpeg -s 720x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 25 -f alsa -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -an -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.149:1234/test.ffm  -vn -c:a aac -strict -2 -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.149:1235/test.ffm`,

Comment: using this command ffmpeg and ffserver work but ffplay keeps buffering and gives no output.  I'll try to send the to media separatly and thne mux them. thank you again